# Any CLI HTML validator running locally and detecting dead internal links

Tags: command-line, websites

I am looking for any HTML validator that fullfils following requirement

- runs locally on a local files (without internet connectivity)
- detects dead internal links
- does not detect working links as invalid
- runs in a command line

I am looking for a tool that would detect `<a href="nonexisting_local_file.html>` `<img src=not_existing_file.png>` and so on.

Comment: I know about https://validator.w3.org/checklink

I tried using it, may be turn to be useful but for now I opened 
https://github.com/w3c/link-checker/issues/52
https://github.com/w3c/link-checker/issues/54
https://github.com/w3c/link-checker/pull/53

as it seems to have false positives and is not installable locally

Answer (score 0):

- this [site-graph tool](https://github.com/tomlinsonk/site-graph) is promising as a base, but not exactly ready

  - remember to use `--visit-external` - it is disabled by default!
- [linkchecker](https://github.com/linkchecker/linkchecker) works very nicely

  - `linkchecker https://matkoniecz.github.io/dead_links_testing_site/`
  - outputting site graph is one of listed features! So detecting orphaned pages should be also feasible...
  - `linkchecker https://matkoniecz.github.io/dead_links_testing_site/ --verbose -o csv` seems parsable to detect orphaned pages
  - [has problems with utf-8 support](https://github.com/linkchecker/linkchecker/issues/554)
- https://validator.w3.org/checklink
- [another option](https://superuser.com/a/139468/376651) is wget and parsing its log. Mentioning for completeness but it looks like a nasty quagmire for me.

  - `wget --spider  -o wget.log  -e robots=off --wait 1 -r -p https://matkoniecz.github.io/dead_links_testing_site/`
  - `cat wget.log | grep 404`
- https://github.com/LukasHechenberger/broken-link-checker-local

  - `blcl -ro . --filter-level 3`
  - `blcl -ro . --filter-level 3 | grep 'BROKEN'`
  - UTF-8 [support has some issues](https://github.com/LukasHechenberger/broken-link-checker-local/issues/50) - see an upstream [issue](https://github.com/stevenvachon/broken-link-checker/issues/234)
  - also, it is known to [hang randomly](https://github.com/stevenvachon/broken-link-checker/issues/90) (reported in 2017)
- [html-proofer by gjtorikian](https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-proofer)

  - Link check fails when `example` is linked instead of `example.html` while it works at Github Pages.

(copied from my https://github.com/matkoniecz/website-checklist/blob/master/validators.md#detecting-dead-links that may be more up to date)